# Count the users based on category in nested list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list with two sub lists.
Here it looks like this

```
a = [['user1', 'referral'], ['user2', 'referral'], ['user1', 'referral'], ['user1', 'affiliate'], ['user7', 'affiliate'], ['user1', 'affiliate'], ['user9', 'affiliate'], ['user4', 'cpc'], ['user4', 'referral'], ['user2', 'referral'], ['user7', 'affiliate'], ['user14', 'cpc'], ['user3', 'orgainic'], ['user2', 'orgainic'], ['user4', 'cpc'], ['user2', 'cpc'], ['user8', 'cpc'], ['user2', 'orgainic']]
```

I want to count the users(unique) based on the category.

Required:

```
required = [['referral',3],['affiliate',3],['cpc',4],['orgainic',2]]
```

Output I got:

```
{'referral': 3, 'affiliate': 2, 'cpc': 4, 'orgainic': 3}
```

It was counting wrong.

Here's the Code i tried:

```
a = [['user1', 'referral'], ['user2', 'referral'], ['user1', 'referral'], ['user1', 'affiliate'], ['user7', 'affiliate'], ['user1', 'affiliate'], ['user9', 'affiliate'], ['user4', 'cpc'], ['user4', 'referral'], ['user2', 'referral'], ['user7', 'affiliate'], ['user14', 'cpc'], ['user3', 'orgainic'], ['user2', 'orgainic'], ['user4', 'cpc'], ['user2', 'cpc'], ['user8', 'cpc'], ['user2', 'orgainic']]

required = [['referral',3],['affiliate',3],['cpc',4],['orgainic',2]]

c = {}
visits = []
for i in a:
    # print(i)
    for j in i[1:]:
        if j not in c and i[0] not in visits:
            c[j] = 1
            visits.append(i[0])
        elif j in c and i[0] not in visits:
            c[j] = c[j]+1
print(c)
```

Help me with some solutions...

Comment: A very simple solution could be `list(c.items())`.

Answer (score 3):

This is one approach using `collections.defaultdict`.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [['user1', 'referral'], ['user2', 'referral'], ['user1', 'referral'], ['user1', 'affiliate'], ['user7', 'affiliate'], ['user1', 'affiliate'], ['user9', 'affiliate'], ['user4', 'cpc'], ['user4', 'referral'], ['user2', 'referral'], ['user7', 'affiliate'], ['user14', 'cpc'], ['user3', 'orgainic'], ['user2', 'orgainic'], ['user4', 'cpc'], ['user2', 'cpc'], ['user8', 'cpc'], ['user2', 'orgainic']]
result = defaultdict(int)
seen = set()
for k, v in a:
    key = "{}_{}".format(k, v)
    if key not in seen:
        result[v] += 1
        seen.add(key)
print(list(map(list, result.items())))
```

**Output:**

```
[['referral', 3], ['affiliate', 3], ['cpc', 4], ['orgainic', 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

First let's make the entries unique:

```
c = {tuple(sublist) for sublist in a}
```

Now we have a unique pairs of user and type.

For the count we don't need users, so let's make it a list with only second argument:

```
c = [elem[1] for elem in c]
```

And now we can count it easily:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(c)
```

Result: `Counter({'cpc': 4, 'affiliate': 3, 'referral': 3, 'orgainic': 2})`

---

Now to put it all together:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(elem[1] for elem in {tuple(sublist) for sublist in a})
```

Answer (score 1):

### `defaultdict` and for loop based solution

This can be done using `defaultdict`:

```
d = defaultdict(set)
for user, category in a:
    d[category].add(user)
res = [[category, len(users)] for category, users in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
# [['affiliate', 3], ['cpc', 4], ['orgainic', 2], ['referral', 3]]
```

### `groupby` based solution

Or, this can be done using `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

a = [['user1', 'referral'], ['user2', 'referral'], ['user1', 'referral'], ...]

# Sort the items according to the category so groupby will collect the pairs accordingly
res = {category: len({user for user, _ in pairs}) for category, pairs in
       groupby(sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1)), key=itemgetter(1))}

res = [list(pair) for pair in res.items()]
```

Output:

```
# [['affiliate', 3], ['cpc', 4], ['orgainic', 2], ['referral', 3]]
```

Comment: how to convert it to the nested list as required output.

Comment: @SmackAlpha, added the last line in the code example to convert to a list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case for pandas, your list is already in the right shape:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [['user1', 'referral'], ['user2', 'referral'], ['user1', 'referral'], ['user1', 'affiliate'], ['user7', 'affiliate'], ['user1', 'affiliate'], ['user9', 'affiliate'], ['user4', 'cpc'], ['user4', 'referral'], ['user2', 'referral'], ['user7', 'affiliate'], ['user14', 'cpc'], ['user3', 'orgainic'], ['user2', 'orgainic'], ['user4', 'cpc'], ['user2', 'cpc'], ['user8', 'cpc'], ['user2', 'orgainic']]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.columns=["user", "type"]

unique_per_type = df.groupby("type")["user"].unique()
```

Now unique_per_type is:

```
type
affiliate            [user1, user7, user9]
cpc          [user4, user14, user2, user8]
orgainic                    [user3, user2]
referral             [user1, user2, user4]
Name: user, dtype: object
```

And you can do things like:

```
# access length by key
len(unique_per_type["affiliate"]) 

# or use it like a dict
for key, val in unique_per_type.items():
    print(key, len(val)))
```

This solution adds pandas, which is a huge dependency. But once you have your data in a DataFrame, you can do lots of things with it:

```
df["user"].unique() # shows all unique users

df.query("user=='user1'") # shows all observations involving user1
```